# Javascript - Update to pipe delimiter with array that contains commas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, delimiter

I've been looking through stack overflow and the internet in general for hours with no solution in site yet...

I'll explain what I'm attempting to do - I'm building a list, then using php **explode** command by comma so I can loop through it, and insert each record into the database.

However, I'm building the array javascript, and the values I'm building the array off of, contain commas, separating first name and last name (Format Ex: Firstname, Lastname).

I'm a beginner and I'm still learning, so any help to point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I'm wondering if I need to do math to count the commas on the php side in order to separate based off the comma count, or if this is achievable in javascript using regex..

Everything I've been looking at seems like I may have to learn some regex to resolve this... Perhaps there's a built in jQuery command to change delimiter that I haven't been able to find?

```
var labels = $('.list-left ul li.active').map(function(){
                    return $(this).text().split(',').join('|');
                }).get();
```

Comment: Can you use a different delimiter to separate your records? That would mean you don't have to worry about the commas that exist in the data.

Comment: Curious why you're not sending JSON and using `json_decode`...

Comment: Jared Smith - That is an excellent idea! Like I said, I'm still learning, so sometimes I just need a little nudge in the right direction. I should be able to resolve this problem using JSON. Thanks for taking the time to reply! Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var test='test1,test2,test3,test4';
var test_new=test.replace(new RegExp(',','g'), '|');
console.log(test_new);
```

Comment: I can replace the commas in the string like your example, but the issue was I had a comma within the value, so it'd look like: firstname,(comma in value) lastname ,(comma delimiter) firstname, lastname, firstname, lastname... However someone posted about using JSON decode, which I think is a great idea that would solve this problem quickly. I really appreciate your reply and attempt to help! Best Regards.